# So slow to receive magento order email

Tags: orders, email

We have a magento website. I found that It takes 6-10 min to receive the order email. It supposes to receive it right away. Does any of you know why?  It shouldn't be so slow.

Answer (score 5):

On newer versions (1.9.1 and later), Magento queues the transactional emails and sends them out on a schedule. There will be a delay between when the order is placed and when the email is sent, unless the order is placed just before the cron job that sends the email triggers.